# AWS Nginx "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I use AWS: ELB (classic) → EC2 (with Node.js)

**Problem.** Sometimes some requests return 502 Bad Gateway error. In Nginx error log a I see "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream" error.

*Not timeout issue.*
This error happens the same second this request in handled by Node.js application. So it is not a timeout issue because of the long response.

*Client doesn't break connection.* I tried to make request programaticly (to be sure that client doesn't break connection). And sometimes got the same error, while test client-application got response with 502 error from Ngnix.

Who can close connection and why?
How to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you try this setting ```proxy_ignore_client_abort on;``` ?

Comment: Any luck? Im facing the same issue, got the error immediately

Comment: Is your application sending non-empty data when this request is made?

Comment: Client doesn't abort session. Client gets error fom proxy

Comment: Our application gets requrst and starts to handle it. Error happens to quick, before our application prepare response (I suppose that)

Answer (score 0):

Who can close connection and why?
That error from Nginx is indicating that the connection was closed by your upstream server (i.e., "node.js")
you can solve this by setting a higher timeout value for the proxy:

```
location / {
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

Documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html